# cut user id mongoose response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to response from my backend a piece of user *id by using lodash, i tryed with id*.slice(2, 9) but i get a response without _id. What i'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.

```js
getUserData: (req, res, next) =>{
        User.findById(req.params.userId,
        (err, user) => {
            if (!user)
                return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: 'User record not found.' });
            else
                return res.status(200).json({ status: true, user: _.pick(user, ['_id'.slice(2, 9), 'domain', 'store', 'settings']) });
            }
        );
    },
```

Comment: A string of `_id` is 3 characters long.  You are substringing off of that string, not the value of the _id in the record

Comment: i'm getting a response _id = '5faf1265350d5637fcb11041'

Comment: `5faf1265350d5637fcb11041` is the value of `user._id`, not the string `'_id'`.  Pick is used to grab keys out of an object.  This looks like an improper use of pick.  It is not intended for manipulating values of keys from an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

To cut the `ObjectId` is necessary first to parse to string, so you need something like this:

```js
var newUserId = user._id.toString().substring(3,user._id.toString().length)
```

But there is a problem (I think, not tested). If you try to store the cut `id` into a `model` object, maybe mongoose don't allow you to add an string (and no valid `ObjectId`) value instead of `ObjectId`.

Maybe is neccesary create another object instead of the model with the schema.

---

Old answer (unrelated) but maybe usefull for somebody:

If you want to hide the result just use `select()` into your query.

You run a query and then select which fields do you want to get or not into the response.

The proper way to code it is as follows:

```js
query.select({ field1: 1, field2: 1 });
//or
query.select('-field1');
//and many other ways
```

Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually need to cut a piece of user id, i modified the title of question.

Comment: Sorry. Can you post an example of the expected value when you cut?

Comment: I'm getting '5faf1265350d5637fcb11041' as response, i need 'f1265350d5637' or similar

Comment: Ok, I think now I've understand. Is necessary parse the `ObjectId` to string to use the string functions.

Comment: Thanks! thats ok, i will not store the modified id into my DB, it's only to handle frontend functions, toString() method is what i need to make this

Comment: That's nice. Also if for some reason you cannot add the new `_id` into the object, I think adding this trick just before should work: `user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))`

Answer (score 2):

```
getUserData: (req, res, next) =>{
        User.findById(req.params.userId,
        (err, user) => {
            if (!user)
                return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: 'User record not found.' });
            else {
                let json = { status: true, user: _.pick(user, ['_id', 'domain', 'store', 'settings']) };
                
                json.user._id = json.user._id.slice(2, 9);
                
                return res.status(200).json(json);
              }
            }
        );
    },
```

- Pick the parts you want
- Slice the _id to replace it with just the part you want
- return the object

Comment: Thanks, it's necesary to parse the id object with toString() to apply slice method

Comment: Ah, that's true.  In mongo shell you would `_id.str.slice`.  So yeah, if `toString()` will get you the hex value in javascript you would need to use that